# How can I let Users compare each other data in chart with Chartkick in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, chartkick

Im working on a small personal Rails app. I want the Users to be able to compare each others data if they are following each other. For example. User A. have been typing in his driving distances for a month. User B has done the same. User A is following user B and wants to compare their km/miles driven through that period?

I´m using Chartkick and I have all models and controller up and running.

I just want to know if it is possible to do this kind of comparison and I would be very greatfull if someone could give me some heads up about how to do this?

with thanks in advance